# What is toggle?

Tags: verilog

```verilog
`timescale 1us/1us

module inverter_tb();
  reg a;
  wire z;
  
  inv u1(a,z);
  
  initial begin
    a = 0;
    #100 $finish;
  end
  
  always begin
    #10 a = ~a;
  end
  
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("output.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0);
  end
endmodule
```

I was asked to "toggle each 10us (period: 20us)" in this code.
But I don't know what toggle means.
Should I just change `#1` under `always begin` to `#10`?

Comment: ask the person that asked you to "toggle"

Comment: it usually means to switch state

Comment: x = NOT(x); // toggle x

Comment: Dictionary: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toggle#dictionary-entry-2 "to switch between two different options"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is trivially answered by dictionary lookup and is not EE-specific.

Answer (score 2):

A toggle switch is a switch with two positions, and a lever arm to switch it between those two.

By analogy, in electronics, a toggle is something that has two stable states (high/low, on/off, etc), and which can be switched between those states.

The verb "to toggle" is then the act of switching something to its other state.  If it was on, toggling it turns it off. Toggling it again turns it back on.